# Use a C# CLR to sort data in arrays

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr

I followed a tutorial and successfully created a Visual Studio project which attaches a *C# CLR Stored Procedure* to my SQL Server database.

I want to benchmark the time it would take to pair rows of a table based on the values of fields. The result would look like a 2 level tree.

My hope is that if I perform this in memory and then write the results back to SQL Server I will speed the process up by reducing IO.

At the moment, my CLR procedure takes a table of values from a database and returns them to the client (SSMS).

```
public static void SqlStoredProcedure1 ()
{
    int[] Column1 = new int[75000];
    string[] Column2 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column3 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column4 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column5 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column6 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column7 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column8 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column9 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column10 = new string[75000];
    string[] Column11 = new string[75000];

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Context Connection=true";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SQL QUERY - I REPLACED IT FOR PRIVACY";
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(rdr);
    rdr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I want to move all rows into arrays.

Comment: It's unclear at the moment what you're planning to do - maybe add some sample data and what the result would look like? At the moment, it sounds like you're wanting to do things with sets of data and joining those sets - things that a *relational* database is very good at.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There are 11 fields, I am comparing combinations of fields in row x to x+n. When I find a match I update row x+n with the row id of x. This takes ~30 minutes because it happens in a loop with complicated logic and update statements. My hope is if I do the work in memory (arrays) in either C# or better yet C++ I can speed to work up.